# Regex for email headers and merging into a single expression

Tags: regex

I'm a bit of a novice with Regex and I'm trying to create an expression that can pull out key bits of data from my email header. I have some of the individual expressions but I'm unsure how to group them all together.

Take this example:

```
 ** PROBLEM Service Alert: ho-server-01 /Disk Usage is WARNING **
```

I want to be able to pull out:

- The first word e.g. PROBLEM - `(\w+)`
- The server (after :) e.g. ho-server-01 - `(?<=:)(.*)(?<=\s)` - I want everything from : to the end of the server name but this is wrong currently
- The status (after /) e.g. Disk Usage is WARNING - `(?<=/)(.*)(?<=\s)` - I want everything from the / to the end of the end of WARNING but this is wrong.

Then I want to make this into a single regex expression. I believe we use the [a|b|c] but I might be wrong.

Some more example headers:

```
** PROBLEM Service Alert: ho-server-01 /Disk Usage is WARNING **
** PROBLEM Service Alert: ho-server-01 /File Director Component Service is CRITICAL **
** RECOVERY Service Alert: ho-server-01 /File Director Component Service is OK **
** RECOVERY Service Alert: ho-server-01 /Drive H: Disk Usage is OK **
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use 3 capture groups with a single expression instead of multiple separate ones.

```php
^\*\*\s+(\w+)\s[^:]*:\s+(\S+)\s+/(.+?)\s+\*\*$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `\*\*` Match `**`
- `\s+(\w+)\s` Capture in **group 1** matching 1+ word chars between whitespace chars
- `[^:]*:\s+` match 0+ times any char other than `:`, then match : and 1+ whitespace chars
- `(\S+)` Capture **group 2**, match 1+ times a non whitespace char *(or use `(\w+(?:-\w+)+)` for a more precise match)*
- `\s+/` Match 1+ whitespace chars and `/`
- `(.+?)` Capture **group 3**, match 1+ times any char as least as possible (non greedy)
- `\s+\*\*` Match 1+ whitespace chars and `**`
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9TVL1O/1)